Web ACL count baced rule doesn't block requests when reach the threshold
Some time ago we faced the problem, that one of our endpoint was called by the bots multiple time, and it cause some problems in our app.
So we decide to use AWS WAF to protect our backend application load balancer.
To apply this I use count-baced rule for the particular endpoint /api/users/validate-phone and setup the threshold of 100 requests per 300 seconds.
The problem is that when I tried to test it I got up to 1000 successfull responses from this endpoint before the firewall start to block them (1000 is not the higher number, It's just max amount of parallel requests I've tried.
Looks like it pass all the requests per second, and only after some delay counts them and block the endpoint, because the second call with 1000 requests returns 403 response.
Here is the example of rule:
{
"Name": "DevBackendLoginCountRequestsRule",
"Priority": 0,
"Action": {
  "Block": {
    "CustomResponse": {
      "ResponseCode": "403",
      "CustomResponseBodyKey": "BotProtectionResponseBody"
    }
  }
},
"VisibilityConfig": {
  "SampledRequestsEnabled": true,
  "CloudWatchMetricsEnabled": true,
  "MetricName": "DevBackendLoginCountRequestsRule"
},
"Statement": {
  "RateBasedStatement": {
    "Limit": "100",
    "EvaluationWindowSec": 300,
    "AggregateKeyType": "CONSTANT",
    "ScopeDownStatement": {
      "ByteMatchStatement": {
        "FieldToMatch": {
          "UriPath": {}
        },
        "PositionalConstraint": "ENDS_WITH",
        "SearchString": "/api/users/validate-phone",
        "TextTransformations": [
          {
            "Type": "NONE",
            "Priority": 0
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}

}
And this is the sample of js code, how I've tested this endpoint:
const callApi = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('https://api.my-backend.com/api/users/validate-phone');
  return response.status;
}

for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  callApi().then(status => {
    console.log(`call ${i} status`, status);
  });
}

Here is what the AWS interface shows, here is shown that 1000 requests were successful:

Also I've checked the CloudWatch logs, and it shows that all the requests where processed.
What have I done wrong? The rule that could pass bots requests, and only after blocked them don't have any sense.
